# AngularJS inject $timeout to a link?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-jasmine, karma-mocha

So here is what my issue is:

i have a directive:

```
  autocompleteDirective.$inject = ['$timeout'];
  function autocompleteDirective($timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        searchParam: '=ngModel',
        suggestions: '=data',
        onType: '=onType',
        onSelect: '=onSelect',
        autocompleteRequired: '='
      },
      controller: autocompleteController,
      link: autocompleteLink,
      templateUrl:'modules/components/autocomplete/templates/autocomplete.html'
    };
  }
```

my Link function looks like this:

```
function autocompleteLink(scope, element, attrs) {

    $timeout(function() {
      scope.initLock = false;
      scope.$apply();
    }, 250);
  .... some other code 

}
```

and my controller (not really relevant) :

```
  autocompleteController.$inject = ['$scope'];
  function autocompleteController($scope) { 

  //scope code
}
```

in my link function, I have a function that is (at the moment) using setTimeout:

```
  if (attrs.clickActivation) {
      element[0].onclick = function() {
        if (!scope.searchParam) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            scope.completing = true;
            scope.$apply();
          }, 200);
        }
      };
    }
```

I would like to unit test this certain block of code, but my unit tests fails:

```
elem.triggerHandler('click');
      expect(scope.completing).to.equal(true);
```

even though, in the coverage report, i can see that the logic does successfully execute when the triggerHandler is clicked.

what i believe the culprit is the timeout.

digging around SO and other websites, i found using $timeout works best due to its exposure to "flush()" method.

my question is, how do I "inject" $timeout to the link function?

the previous examples i have see like injecting $timeout directly to directive, and then nesting the link function() inside the directive declaration:

```
function directive($timeout){
return {
  link: function(scope, attrs) {
    $timeout(blah!) //timeout is useable here...
}
}
```

The above doesn't work for me since i am not creating the function inside the directive function...so based on the model i am using, how can i use $timeout in a link?